# I tried to implement abstract class and interface in a class and only interface members got called and abstract method didnt?

Tags: c#

```
public abstract class AbsClass
{
    public abstract int Add(int num1, int num2);
}
public interface Iinterface1
{
     void print1();
}
public interface Iinterface2
{
     void print2();
}
class Program : AbsClass,Iinterface1,Iinterface2
{
    public void print1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print I1");
    }
    public void print2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Print I2");
    }

    public override int Add(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        p.Add(20, 40);
        p.print1();
        p.print2();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

I tried to implement both abstract and interface in a single class and only interface methods got called and abstract did not, I am a beginner in programming..

Comment: You are not using a result from `p.Add(20, 40);` (i.e. not using `Console.WriteLine` to write the output), so it might seem that the method was not called

Comment: Just a note: You shouldn't start methods with uppercase, use camel case: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @pczeus, this code is C#, not Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to actually use the return value of `p.Add(20, 40)`; try:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Program p = new Program();
    int sum = p.Add(20, 40);
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of 20 and 40 is " + sum);
    p.print1();
    p.print2();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your abstract class have int function, and in the main method you just give parameters to your function.If you want to write sum in console you must write like this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args) {

    Program p = new Program();

    Console.WriteLine(p.Add(20, 40));
    p.print1();
    p.print2();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I hope this work, and sorry on my bad english :D